# $\gcd(8,16)$ with Euclidean algorithm

Tags: algebra-precalculus, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

Using the Euclidean algorithm, where the last nonzero remainder is the gcd, I proceed directly to this result

$16=2\cdot 8+0$

which doesn't have a last nonzero remainder! But clearly $\gcd(8,16)=8$. Why did $8$ not show up in my standard Euclidean procedure above?

Comment: The Euclidean  "remainder" sequence is $\,16,8,0.\,$ What is the last nonzero element?  The sequence means $\ \gcd(16,8) = \gcd(8,0)\, [= 8]\ \ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood the final step of the Euclidean algorithm. Once you reach $0$, it is the smallest of the two *other* numbers in the final step that is the $\gcd$. And in this case, the two other numbers are $8$ and $16$.

You *always* reach $0$ at some point. That is how you know you are finished. Once you have reached $0$ you need to take a step back to find the $\gcd$.

I like to apply the Euclidean algorithm the following way:
$$
\gcd(16,8)=\gcd(16-2\cdot 8,8)\\
=\gcd(0,8)
$$
together with the general assumption that $\gcd(0,n)=n$. This way, it's easier to immediately spot which number is actually the $\gcd$, without having to analyze the terms of the final line.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that "once you reach zero, it's the smallest of the two other numbers in the final step that is gcd".  Yes I know we always reach zero by this method, and I was taught that the gcd is the last nonzero remainder, prior to the zero-remainder row. So I was confused to follow the algorithm and get directly to the row with zero remainder, and not having anything above that row! I'm roughly following the procedure http://math.cmu.edu/~bkell/21110-2010s/extended-euclidean.html